# Using AvalonEdit in Sharpdevelop 3.x

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop, icsharpcode, avalonedit

I am very curious to know if it is possible to replace the normal ICSharpCode.TextEditor with AvalonEdit in Sharpdevelop 3.x. Frankly speaking AvalonEdit is way too better than ICSharpCode.TextEditor, so it would be better to use AvalonEdit in Sharpdevelop 3.x.

I am currently not in a position to use Sharpdevelop 4, it would be better if I can use that new code editor in old Sharpdevelop 3.x.

Can anyone please shed some light on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of SharpDevelop 3.x is hard-coded to use ICSharpCode.TextEditor. You can use an AddIn to replace the text editor (see samples/DisplayBinding/AlternateEditor), but you lose all of the following features:

- Code completion
- Refactoring
- Search + Replace
- Forms designer
- and some more...

All of those features were rewritten to use the new text editor interfaces in SharpDevelop 4. This took us several months of development time.

So no, using AvalonEdit in SD 3.x is not possible unless you have a **lot** of time to spend backporting these changes.

By the way: why can't you use SharpDevelop 4.0?